# Real Analysis question involving Archimedean property or not?

Tags: real-analysis

For real numbers $x,y$, suppose $y-x>1$.  Prove: $∃ n ∈ \Bbb{Z}, n ∈ (x, y)$

I have been procrastinating about how to start this problem.  Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Comment: The statement you have to prove implies that for every real number $x$ there is an integer $n$ such that $n\gt x.$ I don't believe you can prove that without the Archimedean property. (How is $\mathbb Z$ defined in your text, and how is the Archimedian property stated?) Once you know thee is an integer greater than $x,$ it's not too hard to show that the least such integer is less than $y.$

Comment: The set $\{k \in \mathbb Z : k > x\} \subseteq \mathbb R$ is bounded below (by $x$), so it has an infimum. Let $n$ be that infimum. Show that $x < n \leq x+1 < y$.

Comment: @Bungo The set has an infimum if it's bounded **and nonempty**. I think it's the latter point that the OP was worried about. I could be wrong, but that's the impression I got from the title of the question.

Comment: @bof Yes, good point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to use is the "least upper bound property" of the real numbers.

Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, $y - x > 1$.

Consider the set $\{k \in \mathbb{Z}: k \leq y\}$. Clearly this set is bounded above by $y$, and it's a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. You know it's nonempty, because given any $y \in \mathbb{R}$ you can always find an integer smaller than it. (See the end of my post for an explicit proof of this.)

By the least upper bound property, it has a supremum. Let $n = \sup\{k \in \mathbb{Z}: k \leq y\}$. This supremum is in fact a maximum, because if $n \not \in \{k \in \mathbb{Z}: k \leq y\}$, then $n > y$. Now $n > n - \frac{n-y}{2} > y$, contradicting the definition of a supremum. Thus we know that $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

If $n \neq y$, then $n < y$. If $y - n ≥ 1$, then $y - (n+1) ≥ 0$, contradicting that $n = \max\{k \in \mathbb{Z}: k \leq y\}$. Hence $y - n < 1$. But then $y - x = y - n + n - x > 1$, so $n - x > 1 - (y - n) > 1 - 1 = 0$. Thus $n \in (x, y)$.

Finally you need to treat the case where $n = y$ separately, and show that $n-1 \in (x, y)$. This similar and I leave it as an exercise :)

**Proof that $\{k \in \mathbb{Z}: k \leq y\}$ is nonempty**

Suppose $y ≥ 0$. Then $0 \in \{k \in \mathbb{Z}: k \leq y\}$.
Suppose $y < 0$. Then by the Archimedean property of the real numbers, there exists a natural number $m$ such that $m = m\times 1 > -y$. Now $-m \in \mathbb{Z}$ is in $\{k \in \mathbb{Z}: k \leq y\}$. In each case we have shown the set to be nonempty.

**Addendum**

You might be wondering why I chose the set $\{k \in \mathbb{Z}: k \leq y\}$. If I chose to work with $\{k \in \mathbb{Z}: k < y\}$, I wouldn't have had two cases to work with later on because we would already have $n < k$. I wrote it out like this so that you can re-do the entire proof in a better way, so it gives you something to work with. (Okay I lied, the real reason is: I couldn't figure out a nice way of showing that $\sup\{k \in \mathbb{Z}: k < y\} = \max\{k \in \mathbb{Z}: k < y\}$. It's obvious because "it's a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$"!, but I believe every part of a proof for a question as we've been given should only use elementary tools.)

Comment: Of course the Archimedean property follows from the least upper bound property, but it's slightly odd to cite the Archimedean property when the proof of that property is just like your main proof. Why not just say something like this: Since $\mathbb Z\ne\emptyset,$ either (case 1) $\{k\in\mathbb Z:k\lt y\}\ne\emptyset$ or (case 2) $\{k\in\mathbb Z:k\ge y\}\ne\emptyset.$ In one case there is a supremum, which is a maximum; in the other case there is an infimum, which is a minimum . . .

Comment: Ah yes that's much nicer. I'm basically here answering questions because I want to learn, thank you for the comment :)